# Making functions public in a Javascript IFFE when declared in multiple files

Tags: javascript, minify, accessor, iife

I have some Javascript code spread over multiples files, yet I want to facilitate minification with an IFFE. Some methods must remain public.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) suggests the implementation of accessors:

```
var counter = (function(){
  var i = 0;

  return {
    get: function(){
      return i;
    },
    set: function( val ){
      i = val;
    },
    increment: function() {
      return ++i;
    }
  };
}());
```

Unfortunately, declaring these from `return` is not easy when such functions are declared in multiple files.

Is the following a proper solution? If not, what is?

```
var counter = (function(){

  var i = 0;

  // Import js file 1...
  this.get = function(){ return i; };

  // Import js file 2...
  this.set = function( val ){ i = val; };

  // Import js file 3...
  this.increment = function() { return ++i; };

  return this;

}());
```

**P.S.**: I want to be able to perform the following calls:

```
counter.get();
counter.set(33);
counter.increment();
```

Comment: It's not a proper solution because `this` inside this IIFE will refer to the `window` object. Also, what exactly are you trying to do? I have troubles to understand the "import js file 1..." comments in your code.

Comment: It means I use a tool to concatenate pieces of Javascript from multiple files into a wrapping IIFE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the pattern that you are interested in is something like this:

```
//file 1
var xy = (function (that) {
    that.prop1 = 1;
    return that;
}(xy || {}));


//file2
var xy = (function (that) {
    that.prop2 = 2;
    return that;
}(xy || {}));
```

This will result in a single global object `xy` that has two properties:

```
xy = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2
};
```

Comment: Ok, I guess the property can be a function too, which I could call later, something like xy.myfunction(...), correct?

Comment: Yes, it can be a function or anything else. You can also put any "private" functions or variables (like `var a = 1` or `function func(){...}`) inside the IIFEs, but only the actual properties of `that` can be accessed across the different files.

Comment: Last question I guess {} means empty object if xy has not been created before, correct?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I know my answer lacks a bit of explanation, but that's exactly what's happening. If `xy` doesn't already exist, a new object is created and if `xy` exists, the already created object will be used.

Comment: No, one could say I am still not an expert with Javascript. Thanks.